# Reversible ways of temporarily breaking a Linux distribution

Tags: linux

I'm curious what are the reversible ways of temporary breaking a Linux distribution and if it's possible to revert them without rebooting.

Here's the latest gem which I found:

```bsh
sudo mount -o remount,nosymfollow /
```

After running this command I couldn't run anything else, not even `/usr/sbin/mount` or `/usr/bin/bash`. The system kept on running but launching new programs was impossible. I couldn't even reboot, so I invoked SysRQ + SUB. I had a bash session opened, but I had no clue how to remount using `symfollow`.

Various other mount options can also wreak havoc to your system: `nosuid`, `nodev`, `noexec` when applied to certain directories will effectively break the system.

Comment: You should maybe provide more details as being able to do it as root or a random user, etc.

Comment: Are you interested in ways of temporarily breaking a distro which can be reversed while the system is still up, but would be impossible to fix without a rescue system once the system has tried to reboot? (I’m thinking of things like renaming the dynamic linker...)

Comment: @StephenKitt why not? ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure how broad you want this question to be.  In the past I've built scripts to repeatedly screw up system networking and fix it.  Most of the things you can immagine to screw up a live system will screw it up for a namespace.  There may then be ways to fix one namespace from another using `nsenter` (not sure, never tried) or otherwise propigating changes from one ns to another.  So if this is for testing purposes (not just fun) creating screwed up child namespaces can be very effective.

Comment: @PhilipCouling would be nice to see as well. I intended this question to have as many examples as possible of unintentionally or intentionally screwing up your system.

Comment: `mount --bind /dev/null /lib/ld-linux.so.2` would probably bork your system while touching only a single file. Change the version to match your installation. Or mount over top of `/lib/ld-2.17.so`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a high-level concept.  Most of the things that might "wreak havoc" would be limited to a namespace.  So if you want to break everything and then fix it, you might be doing this for curiosity or possibly for testing purposes.

Also, what you describe in your question only really broke the command-line.  A running process that expects to interact with the kernel directly (even one dependant on libc) would be unaffected by losing the entire file system.

So if you want a backdoor to recover, you could write yourself something in C that can re-mount.  The important thing is that you use the API [`mount()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) and not the command [`mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).  The running process will not be dependant on the directory tree to do its job.

---

Another fun one is to mess up networking.  I've actually done this deliberately to docker containers to create a sort of [chaos monkey](https://www.gremlin.com/chaos-monkey/).

There's two useful points to attack:

1. Continually re-write `/etc/resolv.conf`.  You can temporarily remove it and then replace it.  This will do a good job of causing a lot of networking jobs to fail.
2. Move the interface to another network namespace (eg: [like this](https://serverfault.com/a/704717/94158)).  *I'll admit I'm not 100% of what happens to open sockets if you do this*.  You can then bring it back and fix up any IP addresses as required.